# Xmonad with fn keys get to work

Tags: ubuntu, xmonad, volume

I am using xmonad and am almost new to it. I installed it on my Lenovo Y700-14ISK with Ubuntu 16.04. I am using gnome-panel with xmonad. How can I make my fn combination keys like changing volume or screen light get to work? I appreciate your help in advance.